# How to make an SQL query result a link to a unique page

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'd like to be able to make a result from my user's query to be able to open a new page if the user clicks it. The queries returned are dependant on what was searched by the user.

I think that  can be used to solve this, but I'm not sure how.

Currently I can search for a result and return matching records, but I can't actually click them and I'm struggling to find a way to do this, as I'm only incurring errors and I can't find any applicable code.

The process I'm trying to implement:

1. You search for something
2. Matching results are returned
3. You can click a result (what I'm attempting)
4. A page related to that result is opened (also what I'm attempting)

I just want to be able to return any of the records I get in a way that allows the user to click them, like a standard search for any webpage.

My code is as follows:

**PHP:**

```
<?php

// Connect to DB
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new MySQLi($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Collect Data
// Ensure user input string only has letter characters
// Unimportant to current problem
if(isset($_POST["aSearch"])) {
  $searchq = $_POST["aSearch"];
  $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq); //Can only search words

// Select records which match the user's input
$sql = "SELECT * FROM birdt WHERE birdName LIKE '%$searchq%'";
}

// Tests if the code been inserted
if ($conn->query($sql)=== TRUE){
  echo "The rows you have searched for are:";
} else {
  echo "Connection failed: ";
  echo $conn->error;
}

// Show fields
$result = $conn->query($sql);

// Output data of each row
if ($result-> num_rows> 0) {
  readfile("ViewReturn.html"); // Returns the file in an HTML Page
  while($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
    // echo "ID: ".$row["id"]. "<br>";
    echo "Bird Name: ".$row["birdName"]. "<br><br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}

// Close connections
if (!function_exists('mysqli_init') && !extension_loaded('mysqli')) {
  echo "There was an error with MySQLi";
} else {
  echo "Closing Connections";
}

$conn-> close();
exit();
?>
```

For example, if this returns "Gull", how could I make this a link to another page?

I'm not sure if it's important, but I return all of my records in a separate HTML file, and I'm willing to change this if necessary.

I'm very inadept at PHP and quite frankly hate this language, but thank you in advance for taking the time to read this and for any help :¬)

Comment: Well, instead of outputting the literal strings you receive back from the query you can output an html anchor ("link") instead. It is as easy as that. If that does not tell you anything, then you did not yet understand the basic concepts of html and the way the web works. Don't get me wrong, that is perfectly fine, we all started once. But there really is little sense in giving you some finished code here you will copy and paste. Instead you should invest time to understand how a link actually works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are doing in readfile("ViewReturn.html"); If it is returning a complete HTML you will have a problema with the echo function after. Because you will have something like this:

```
    <html>

      <body class="">

      </body>
   </html>
         Bird Name: something<br><br>
         Bird Name: something<br><br>
```

I think you want something like:

```
    <html>

      <body class="">
         <a href="yourLink"> Bird Name: something<br><br></a>
         <a href="yourLink"> Bird Name: something<br><br></a>
      </body>
   </html>
```

For that I change you code for something like:

```
// Output data of each row
if ($result-> num_rows> 0) {
  readfile("StartViewReturn.html");
  while($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
    // echo "ID: ".$row["id"]. "<br>";
    echo "<a href="yourLink">Bird Name: ".$row["birdName"]. "</a><br><br>";
  }
  readfile("EndViewReturn.html");
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
```

I strongly recommend to you use a framework. It will help you to organize your code and understand PHP more. At the beginning it could be frustrating but later you will enjoy it (I use Symfony2).